# When using jade's "pretty" option, how do I prevent spaces between elements in a single block?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

In general I like the pretty option. I like my html to be readable and `pretty` helps. But there are times when it gets in the way. For example.

```
x.do-not-care-about-spaces It can go either way here.

y.please-no-spaces These
y.please-no-spaces Should
y.please-no-spaces Touch
```

What I'd like to see is:

```
<x class="do-not-care-about-spaces">It can go either way here.</x>
<y class="please-no-spaces">These</y><y class="please-no-spaces">Should</y><y class="please-no-spaces">Touch</y>
```

But what I do see is

```
<x class="do-not-care-about-spaces">It can go either way here.</x>
<y class="please-no-spaces">These</y>
<y class="please-no-spaces">Should</y>
<y class="please-no-spaces">Touch</y>
```

I know there are several ways to work around this (with css, by putting html in the jade file), but what I'm hoping for is a jade-y way of doing it.

**EDIT:** Updated example with example tags, rather than divs. I am asking specifically about *controlling spaces between DOM nodes in jade's HTML output*, not the visual space between elements on a rendered web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [similar question](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1833) on the github repo and the [essential comment](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1833#issuecomment-70699104) is:

> No, it is not currently possible to force only part of the document into pretty/normal mode. The general recommendation for this is to use the normal (non-pretty) mode which is the default for exactly this reason. You can explicitly add white space using `= ' '` (on its own line) when actually needed for the formatting of the page.

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` element takes up the whole row, so it makes sense that it's rendered as such too.

I think what you need are **`<span>`** tags

```
span.no-space These
span.no-space Will
span.no-space Touch
```

```
<span class="no-space">These</span><span class="no-space">Will</span><span class="no-space">Touch</span>
```

BTW there's also the inline `#[…]` syntax which makes more sense if you're putting tags in one line

```
#[span.no-space These]#[span.no-space Will]#[span.no-space Touch]
```

Note that this syntax will not however make divs appear in one line though, you still have to use spans.

Comment: Perhaps my example was misleading. The blockyness or inlineiness of the tags is not the issue. The visual representation of the rendered page is not. I'm specifically asking about controlling the spaces injected (or not) into the HTML between the DOM nodes. I will update the example to be less misleading.

Comment: @leff I did understand what you meant before, maybe I confused you more with `#[…]` syntax, please disregard that. To put it more clearly, **only span tags** can do what you want. Only when you use span tags in Jade, it would not inject newlines between them. Any other tags will be injected with newlines between them.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks for clarifying. Based on user3351393's answer, it sounds like there is not really a tag agnostic solution.